# How to get rid of the FLICKER on hover using css3 and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this graphic...

http://cheesecake.webparity.net/

I'm getting a flicker on HOVER...

Also, I want a smooth ease in and out of the images (color) on hover... finally, I'd like to ensure that this will be responsive, but I think that this is ok.

Here's the CSS:

```
/* Grayscale rollover */
.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari 
*/
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fix for transition flickering */
}
#layer-0, #layer-1, #layer-2, #layer-3, #layer-4 {
     color: #fff;
}

#currlayer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    float: right;
    right: -5px;
    top:-20px;
    z-index: 20;
}

#map-image {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    float: right;
    right: -5px;
    top:-20px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.column-2 li {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.columns {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.9375em;
    padding-right: 0.9375em;
}
.column-2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 16.66667%;
    float:left;
}
.column-09 {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    float:right;
}
.layers {
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
}
.layers p {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.layer-default {
    background:#444;
    padding:5px 15px 47px;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Here's the Javascript which is where I believe the problem is lying:

When I HOVER over the MAP AREA, I'm taking the data-layersrc and using that to FILL

```
$("area").hover(function () {
    $layer = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".layer-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    $($layer).removeClass("hidden");
    console.log("Image is: " + $(this)[0].dataset.layersrc);
    $("#currlayer").attr("src", $(this)[0].dataset.layersrc.replace("../", ""));
    $("#currlayer").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");

}, function () {
    $(".layer-default > div").addClass("hidden");
    $("#layer-0").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#currlayer").addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Map').imageMapResize();
});
```

I think that the flicker is due to the fact that I'm not rolling over ONE TIME but it's being REPEATED every time I move the mouse.

View this link to see what I want to achieve. The ROLLOVER shows the highlighted ZONES with no flicker.

That's what I'm trying to achieve.

EXAMPLES:
http://jsfiddle.net/eLbpmsaj/

Or this is the best version of what I think works:
https://codepen.io/keishaperry/pen/OMarZQ

Comment: Your images, shown on `mouseenter`, are making the mouse loose focus on the initial element. So the `mouseleave` event occurs. Those are the two handlers in `.hover()`. So you have to think about a delay in between... But that will just "slow" the flickering. I don't know... Play with it. You now know why that happens. Read the documentation... And think. ;)

Comment: Very well... thank you. I shall and let you know my findings.

Comment: Maybe give the img tag a lowsrc attribute with a grayscale image or one that will 'smooth' the transition.

Comment: RRD, please explain what you mean by "lowsrc" attribute?  I have a grayscale and sliced images for the "hover".  The main image is "gray" already.  My whole idea is, when you "role over" the <area> tag, specifically, the "map" area for each layer, the coordinates would "light-up" to reveal the COLOR section, but I couldn't figure that out, so I went with sliced image sections that were 10, 20, 30, and 40 z-index over the "gray" original.  So, as you role over, each section would simple appear (in color) and "show" or "hide" depending on where  your mouse is!  I really need to nail this!